# How to get vehicle information in less than one second?

Tags: veins, sumo

I need to send and receive vehicle updates in less than one second.

I have edited the *.sumo.cfg file and defined the following parameters:

```
<time>
    <step-length value="0.1"/>
</time>

<processing>
      <default.action-step-length value="0.1"/>
</processing>
```

But the settings do not work. I am trying to get the position of a vehicle every 0.1 seconds with the mobility-> getPositionAt (simTime ()) command, but the system updates the position only every second.

Comment: Which Veins and Sumo version are you using?

Comment: You will need to edit your omnetpp.ini file as well

Comment: @JulianHeinovski I am using SUMO 1.2.0 and Veins 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I appreciate the answers. In the omnetpp.ini file just change the parameter `*.manager.updateInterval = 1s` to`*.manager.updateInterval = 0.1s` or to `*.manager.updateInterval = 100ms`.